# How to read in a TSV file from memory and properly iterate through each line

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I will be deploying an application to a read-only file system. Part of this application involves processing a TSV file, which, instead of saving locally, I use `csv.DictReader` to read in the streamed file as a dictionary, convert it to a JSON object that I then pass to another python script, and then from within that python script, I save that JSON object as a TSV file in memory via `csv.DictWriter`.

The step I'm now having trouble with is reading in that in-memory TSV file properly. When I try to iterate through the lines of the file, it prints out not in the usual way it would. How can I properly iterate through each line of the in-memory TSV file?

```
from ast import literal_eval
import csv
import json
import io
from pprint import pprint

# This is the JSON structure that's passed to the python script
infile = ('"[{\\"First_Name\\": \\"Anna\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\", \\"Last_Name\\": '
 '\\"Karenina\\", \\"Places\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard\\", \\"Email\\": '
 '\\"anna.Karenina@ucsf.edu\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8885006000\\", \\"Fax\\": '
 '\\"8885006001\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"1\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", '
 '\\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data '
 'processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical '
 'analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\"},{\\"First_Name\\": \\"UCSF_Weill\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department '
 'of Psychiatry, UCSF Weill Institute for Neurosciences, University of '
 'California, San Francisco, San Francisco, CA 94158\\", \\"Last_Name\\": '
 '\\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", '
 '\\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", '
 '\\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Data '
 'processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical '
 'analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\"}]"')

# Convert json string that's passed to script into literal list of dicts
contents = literal_eval(json.loads(infile))
fieldnames = contents[0].keys()  # Get TSV fieldnames from first dictionary.

# Put list of dicts back into TSV "file" in memory
memory_file = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(memory_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerows(contents)

as_string = memory_file.getvalue()
# print('\n'.join(as_string.splitlines()))

# Open the TSV file from memory and process the contents
for line in as_string:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Try `for line in as_string.splitlines():` to iterate by lines

Comment: Oh, so the answer was in my hidden comment the whole time (*facepalm*). Thank you!